javascript sorting strings starting with a number not working
I am trying to sort an object of strings, which would work with the normal sort function, but I am not able to get it working as the strings start with a number:
e.g.:
{ value: "10 items", value: "5 items", value: "100 items", value: "20 items" }

I want to make it ascending, so it becomes:
5 items
10 items
20 items
100 items
I've been trying to use:
data.sort((a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1).map((a) => { return a;}

But that still shows it as:
10 items
100 items
20 items
5 items

When sorting strings, try to use localeCompare, which should order them correctly. So data.sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b)). Also, you example object is in invalid object, please just print an array there. You can't even sort that, very confusing.

Objects can't have repeating keys, so this doesn't make a lot of sense. Objects also don't have a .sort function, so data.sort() should throw an error.

You need to compare the first parts of your strings numerically, so we split them, get the first element, convert them to int and then we can compare it. See below:


let data = [ "10 items", "5 items", "100 items", "20 items" ];
data.sort((a, b) => {
    let x = parseInt(a.split(" ")[0]);
    let y = parseInt(b.split(" ")[0]);
    if (x === y) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return x > y ? 1 : -1;
    }
});
console.log(data);



Note that I have reinterpreted your input, since the one you have given was obviously wrong, as repeating the same key inside an object (value) in this case is invalid.

I indeed had to modify some things, but this is working for me

As @somethinghere mentioned in the comment you can use localeCompare to sort numerical data


const data = [{ value: "10 items" },
              { value: "5 items"},
              {value: "100 items"},
              {value: "20 items"}
    ];
const result = data.sort((a, b) => a.value.localeCompare(b.value,undefined,{numeric:true}));
console.log(result );




You can extract the numbers with s.slice(0, s.indexOf(' ') and compare them:


let data = [ "10 items", "5 items", "100 items", "20 items" ];
const getNum = s => s.slice(0, s.indexOf(' '));
data.sort((a, b) => (a = getNum(a), b = getNum(b), a-b));
console.log(data);



If you want to speed up you could compare lengths of the numbers first and then compare them char-by-char if the length is equal:
` Chrome/124
-----------------------------------------------------
Alexander      ■ 1.00x | x1000000 223 245 256 304 317
Lajos Arpad      1.69x | x1000000 376 407 426 433 446
Peter Seliger   99.10x |   x10000 221 235 238 247 271
----------------------------------------------------- `

Open in the playground


let data = [ "10 items", "5 items", "100 items", "20 items" ];

// @benchmark Alexander
data.toSorted((a, b) => {
  a = a.slice(0, a.indexOf(' ')), b = b.slice(0, b.indexOf(' '));
  if(a.length > b.length) return 1;
  if(a.length < b.length) return -1;
  for(let i = 0;i < a.length;i++){
    if(a[i] > b[i]) return 1;
    if(a[i] < b[i]) return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});

// @benchmark Peter Seliger
data.toSorted((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true }));

// @benchmark Lajos Arpad
data.toSorted((a, b) => {
    let x = parseInt(a.split(" ")[0]);
    let y = parseInt(b.split(" ")[0]);
    if (x === y) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return x > y ? 1 : -1;
    }
});

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));





First, an object only can have unique keys ... fix the object accordingly.
Second, one only can sort arrays ... the OP wants to sort all of an object's values.
Third, localeCompare does support numeric comparison



console.log(
  Object
    .values({
      value1: "10 items",
      value2: "5 items",
      value3: "100 items",
      value4: "20 items",
      value5: "20 facts",
    })
    .sort((a, b) =>
      a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true })
    )
);
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }



And in case the OP wanted to sort an array of equally structured object items, the above solution slightly changes too ...


console.log(
  [{
    value: '10 items',
  }, {
    value: '5 items',
  }, {
    value: '100 items',
  }, {
    value: '20 items',
  }, {
    value: '20 facts',
  }]
  .sort((a, b) =>
    a.value.localeCompare(b.value, undefined, { numeric: true })
  )
);
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }




slow as hell though...

If you want even faster sorting, you could create a lookup Map that maps a value to a parsed number. Keep in mind that you are replacing memory for speed. There is always a trade-off.


const data = ["10 items", "5 items", "100 items", "20 items"];

const lookup = data.reduce((m, k) =>
  m.set(k, +k.slice(0, k.indexOf(' '))), new Map);

// @benchmark Mr. Polywhirl
data.toSorted((a, b) => lookup.get(a) - lookup.get(b));

// @benchmark Alexander
data.toSorted((a, b) => {
  a = a.slice(0, a.indexOf(' ')), b = b.slice(0, b.indexOf(' '));
  if (a.length > b.length) return 1;
  if (a.length < b.length) return -1;
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] > b[i]) return 1;
    if (a[i] < b[i]) return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});

/* @skip */ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));



